# PJSUA: verbosity of debug information on the application console

Tags: sip, pjsip

If I create an application using PJSUA, then after the pjsua_create() system call, a huge amount of debugging information falls onto the console of my application.
This is convenient at the development stage, but after it interferes with the work with programm.

How can you predefine verbosity level of this debugging information? So that when pjsua_create() is called, it is already set.

Thank you for the informative answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling `pj_log_set_level(int level)` ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__PJ__LOG.htm#gab8f76697c525b7ce55a85da16442d0c1)) for example before `pj_init()`. Also you can define `PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL` const in config_site.h with value suited to your needs at compilation time.

This also may be interesting for you ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__logging__config.htm)).