# How current_acc is modified in pjsip?

Tags: ios, swift, pjsip

When I take a look into iOS Application which uses pjsip I found it. reg_acc_id is define as -1. 
`pjsua_acc_id reg_acc_id = -1;` 
And this reg_acc_id is used to register the user.
`pjsua_acc_add(&acc_cfg, PJ_TRUE, &reg_acc_id);`

```
// To Check registration is successful or not
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
      pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error adding new account", status);
  }

  printf("\nREGISTRATION ACCOUNT ID IS :::: %d\n",reg_acc_id);
  pjsua_acc_set_default(reg_acc_id);
```

`REGISTRATION ACCOUNT ID IS :::: %d\n",reg_acc_id` this line prints "2".... I wonder How? How registration account is incremented by default? What Background process is performed?Any one please clarify my doubts.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation says ([link](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__ACC.htm#gad6e01e4e7ac7c8b1d9f629a6189ca2b2)), third argument of `pjsua_acc_add` is "Pointer to receive account ID of the new account." So it doesn't matter what you have in `reg_acc_id` before call `pjsua_acc_add`. You just saying to this method "place ID of created account in this variable". So I guess, value `-1` in your case mean "account is not registered yet".

**Edit:**

Maybe at the moment when you call pjsua_acc_add, there are some other accounts initialized previously, eg. some local accounts? Set PJ log level at least to 4 (via `pjsua_logging_config` structure passed to `pjsua_init`, or another way ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278162/pjsua-verbosity-of-debug-information-on-the-application-console))) and look for such lines:

```
15:23:50.368    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=<sip:192.168.1.106:51866>
15:23:50.368    pjsua_acc.c  .Account <sip:192.168.1.106:51866> added with id 0
15:23:50.368    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:SOMEONE@SOMEHOST
15:23:50.368    pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:SOMEONE@SOMEHOST added with id 1
```

As you can see in this example there are two accounts created with id's started from 0.

Comment: If there is no any local account, then acc id after call will be 0? after calling ```pjsua_acc_add(&acc_cfg, PJ_TRUE, &reg_acc_id);```where reg_acc_id is -1